# 1. Request for What's the difference in meaning between (Write how you would teach the difference in meaning to the students):

Tags: sentence-meaning

> She wears a dress to work.
>
> She's wearing a dress to work.

please explain the difference in meaning and how it can be taught to students in a way that clarifies their meanings

Answer (score 1):

> She wears a dress to work.

A dress is her *usual attire* at work.

> She is wearing a dress to work.

She is going to work today and either she has a dress on now or she intends to wear a dress to work.

You could, however, convert **is wearing** to the first meaning with the addition of one or more phrases that create that context:

> She is wearing a dress to work ever since her boss commented that jeans were not proper attire for  a law office.

But absent such context, the meanings given above are the most likely.